# Any way to use Aerospike LDT (Large data types) from Node.js Client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aerospike

I am using Node.js aerospike client to access the aerospike server. I wish to use LDTs for storing my data.
I know this feature is still not provided by the Node.js client, but is there any way I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, LDTs are operated upon using the UDF layer by passing the appropriate arguments. Node.js now has the functionality to invoke any UDF. So, technically you should be able to use the LDTs via UDF. However, you need to handle the input output yourself. (You can take a look at how java client is interacting with the LDTs via UDF to get an idea). Is this something that you will be interested to do ?

Answer (score 0):

@vineet.hawal, Node.js client supports LDT from 1.0.34 release.  Please check.
http://www.aerospike.com/download/client/nodejs/notes.html#1.0.35

Answer (score 0):

Aerospike supports large list for node.js , but (when I'm writing this post) you can't find the documentation on aerospike website but only on the doc on github : https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-nodejs/blob/master/docs/largelist.md